# ¿Cómo cargar un formulario mostrando las variables enviadas vía AJAX?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Quiero crear y cargar un formulario que contiene una etiqueta script con las variables que envío usando AJAX y poner este formulario dentro de un div usando html(), por tanto uso la etiqueta object como se muestra en el siguiente código:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "scripts/api.php",
  data:{
    uuid: '03249AAV',
    amount: '100.00',
    userID: '111111'
  },
  cache: false,
  success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){
   $("#b4").html("<object type='text/html' data='scripts/api.php'></object>");
  },
  error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
    console.log( errorThrown );
  }
 });
```

y mi código PHP que crea el formulario recibiendo las variables es el siguiente:

```
<?php
  $uuid = $_POST['uuid'];
  $amount = $_POST['amount'];
  $userID = $_POST['userID'];

  $numrandom = rand(111111,999999);

  $form="
  <form action=\"https://www.mywebsite.com/payment.php?sessionToken=$uuid\" method='post'>
  <script src=\"https://static-content.vnforapps.com/v1/js/checkout.js?qa=true\"
    data-sessiontoken=\"$uuid\"
    data-merchantid=\"$userID\"
    data-buttonsize=\"\"
    data-buttoncolor=\"\" 
    data-merchantlogo =\"icon/logo.png\"
    data-merchantname=\"\"
    data-formbuttoncolor=\"#047AB7\"
    data-purchasenumber=\"$numrandom\"
    data-amount=\"$amount\"
   /></script>
  </form>";
 echo $form;
?>
```

Obtengo el resultado de AJAX dentro del div pero las variables están vacías como se muestra en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado usar en el response de AJAX esta línea `$("#b4").html(data)` pero el formulario no ejecuta el script que lo contiene y no se carga el botón de pago mostrando el div vacío en la página web, es por eso que uso `$("#b4").html("<object type='text/html' data='scripts/api.php'></object>");` en el comienzo de la pregunta. La consola no muestra ningún error.

¿Cómo puedo mostrar estas variables?

Me gustaría su ayuda.

Gracias!

**ACTUALIZO:**

He probado otros métodos dentro del success, uno de ellos ha sido document.write y lo he usado de esta forma:

```
success: function(data){
   document.open();
   document.write(data);
   document.close();
}
```

Sin embargo toda la página queda en blanco y sólo muestra el botón de pago que carga correctamente y lo que deseo es que aparezca solamente en el div de la página. Al parecer necesita una acción tipo submit para el botón se cargue correctamente, ¿Existe algún método que recree ese evento y lo ponga en el div?

Comment: ¿Estás tratando de ejecutar un script de php desde `<object></object>` y agregando variables get a la url de un archivo js?

Comment: @Yikarus Así es, es un formulario de pagos en VISA, que genera un botón de pago al indicar esos parámetros que indico en el código.

Comment: ¿Si pruebas así que ocurre?: `$("#b4").html("<object type='text/html' data='scripts/api.php'>"+data+"</object>");`

Comment: Mira esto https://stackoverflow.com/a/37786551/2516718 puede que necesites llamar a `JSON.stringify()` y usar las variables como se muestra en esta solución. También es posible que requieras el `contentType` pero no soy Php y no puedo ayudar mucho en esa area.

Comment: @A.Cedano Sale igual que en la imagen, no se ven las variables.

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿si en la página que recibe la respuesta Ajax pones el formulario escrito como lo tienes del lado de PHP, con los supuestos valores puestos a mano, el formulario se muestra bien?

Comment: @A.Cedano Así es, el formulario funciona correctamente y ejecuta el script que lo contiene, pero sucede que esas variables no son estáticas, esos valores cambian, si esos valores no están se emite una alerta indicando que se deben completar esos valores.

Comment: Una posible solución sería tener tu formulario del lado del cliente y traer por Ajax solamente los valores que cambian y actualizarlos.

Comment: @derloopkat De acuerdo al link que me enviaste, hice cambios en el código de esta manera: `var arry = {uuid:'03249AAV', amount:'100.00', userID:'148131802'}; var dataString = JSON.stringify(arry); $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "scripts/api.php",data: {myData: dataString},cache: false,success: function(data){ $("#b4").html("<object type='text/html' data='scripts/api.php' ></object>");}, error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){ console.log( errorThrown ); }});` pero sucede lo mismo.

Comment: @A.Cedano anteriormente lo hice así pero el script no los detecta, se comporta como si no le hubieran ingresado ningún dato a pesar que figura en código fuente.

Comment: ¿pero cambiaste también el Php? Es que la variable no se usa igual. `$obj = json_decode($_POST["myData"]);

echo $obj->var;`

Comment: @derloopkat Así es, en PHP lo cambié así: `<?php $obj = json_decode($_POST['myData']); $sessionToken = $obj->uuid; $amount = $obj->amount; $merchantId = $obj->userID; $numrandom = rand(111111,999999); $form="<form action=.." //aquí es lo mismo ?>`

Answer (score 0):

creo que en el código PHP debes crear elementos HTML  con el valor correspondiente en cada caso para que se vean esos elementos en el formulario. Ahora mismo los estás insertando dentro de la etiqueta .
De todas formas, en la propia respuesta del ajax, tal como has editado con el código:

```
success: function(data){   
   document.open();
   document.write(data);
   document.close();
}
```

Ahí mismo, una vez tienes la respuesta, puedes, mediante JavaScript, crear el formulario y sus elementos. Y asignarles el valor correspondiente que venga en la respuesta "data". 
Te pongo un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo:

```
let dynamicform = document.createElement("form");
dynamicform.method = "post";
dynamicform.action = data.URLAction;

let inputs = [
    {value: data.value1, name: 'inputField1'},
    {value: data.value2, name: 'inputField2'},
    {value: data.value3, name: 'inputField2'}
];

_.forEach(inputs, function (param) {
    let inputAux = document.createElement("input");
    inputAux.name = param.name;
    inputAux.value = param.value;
    dynamicform.appendChild(inputAux);
});

$("#divContenedorDelForm").append(dynamicform);
```